# React input focus event to display other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was read some tutorial about this. They told me should using ref to do that.
But It's very general.

Here is my problem:
Basically in `Header` component include `NavBar`, `SearchBar` and `ResultSearch` component.

```
const Header = () => {
return (
    <header className="ss_header">
        <Navbar />
        <SearchBar />
        <ResultSearch />
    </header>
);
};
```

And In `SearchBar` component. Whenever I focused on input text. It emit an event and display `ResultSearch` component by any way (changing style, or ...).

```
class SearchBar extends Component{
render() {

    return (
        <div className="search_bar">
            <section className="search">
                <div className="sub_media container">
                    <form method="GET" action="" id="search_form">
                        <Icon icon="search" />
                        <span className="autocomplete">

                        <input
                            className="search_input"
                            autoCorrect="off"
                            autoComplete="off"
                            name="query"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Search for a movie, tv show, person..." />
                    </span>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Style in `ResultSearch` component. I was set `display: none`.

```
.results_search { display: none; }
```

I think ResultSearch will receive an event from `SearchBar` and set back `display: block` for `ResultSearch` component. Is possible?

How can I handle that?
My Code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/3xv8xnx3z5

Comment: One solution is using redux and if you don't want to use redux you can define handler methods in header components and pass handler as props to SearchBar component and in Header component setState when clicked on searchBar and pass state to other components.
Put your codes on https://codesandbox.io/ to help more.

Comment: Thank @OmiD I was put my Link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

only you should convert Header component like following:

```
class Header extends Component {
  state = {
    focus: false
  };

  handleInputFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ focus: true });
  };

  handleInputBlur = () => {
    this.setState({ focus: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <header className="ss_header">
        <SearchBar
          onFocus={this.handleInputFocus}
          onBlur={this.handleInputBlur}
        />
        {this.state.focus ? <ResultSearch /> : null}
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

and also in SearchBar component add following attributes to your input:

```
onFocus={this.props.onFocus}
onBlur={this.props.onBlur}
```

also, you should remove your CSS about result box.

And, you can see the updated code on the following sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mmj46xkpo9

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what you're trying to achieve.

This is the way you can handle visibility of result of the search. Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for.

https://codesandbox.io/s/7jvz31xr66

Comment: Thank @Amin Paks. Your handle's work for my case. But i keep more simple by just checking through state focus property.