# Detect focus on children component with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component and in general I render input fields inside it.
is there a way to know if the children input has focus?

```
<Component>
    <input />
</Component>

const Component = (props) => return (<div className="nice">{props.children}</div>)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.javascriptstuff.com/event-bubbling/

Comment: If I'm not wrong you can use the onFocus={} listener in the child component on the Input element and use setState for example and send that set value back to ur parent so it knows when the input element is selected. I'm not sure if your working with functional components or class components but this link can help you out if your using class components -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979593/react-input-focus-event-to-display-other-component/50979881

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sandbox that you can check here : https://codesandbox.io/s/chris-lisangola-c53ri-c53ri

From the link that you've posted i seems like the main problem is the way to handle event triggered from a child component to the parent through props.If i'm wrong please let me know.

I've created a child component like this :

```
import React from "react";

export default function Input(props) {
  const { checkFocus } = props;
  return <input onFocus={checkFocus} />;
}
```

And in the child component i've added a event listener of type `focus` that is passed to the parent through the `checkFocus`.

In the parent component `App`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormInput from "./FormInput";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const checkFocus = (e) => {
    console.log(e.type);
    if (e.type === "focus") {
      setText("Focus");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Handle Focus : {text}</h1>
      <FormInput checkFocus={checkFocus} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've done a very basic test so that of there is a focus in the child's input , the text **Focus** is displayed in the `h1 tag`